# mysql group_concat distinct with joins very slow horrible performance

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have the following query which produces the results I need but it's horrible as far as performance on large DB/tables.. can somebody please point out why it's so slow and show me another way of writing this so it's fast.  I takes over an hour to finish!  Plenty of ram.. dedicated server not much else going on it.

```
UPDATE feed.product fp 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  p.date_upd, p.id_product, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT ('https://www.example.com/', pi.`id_image`,'-x_shop/',pl.link_rewrite,'.jpg')) SEPARATOR ",")  AS images 
    FROM db.products p
      LEFT JOIN db.image pi ON (p.id_product = pi.id_product)
      LEFT JOIN db.product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product)
     GROUP BY p.id_product
   ) s ON fp.id_product = s.id_product
SET fp.images = s.images
WHERE fp.image_updated = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find this better with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE feed.product fp 
    SET fp.images = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT ('https://www.example.com/', pi.`id_image`,'-x_shop/',pl.link_rewrite,'.jpg')) SEPARATOR ",")  AS images
                     FROM db.image pi JOIN
                          db.product_lang pl
                          ON pi.id_product = pl.id_product
                     WHERE fp.id_product = pi.id_product
                    )    
    WHERE fp.image_updated = 1;
```

This will be particularly helpful if only a minority of rows in `fp` are being updated.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the suggestion.. I will test it and post back.. can you also please describe to me why it's so slow?  I'm looking for a solution and also to learn as to why it's performing that way.   Also you mentioned if there's minor updates.. sometimes there's lots of rows that needs to get updated.

Comment: @Jake . . . For performance, you need the right indexes on the right columns.